# Visual studio complex Expressions

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2008, expression

Im trying to work out the % Difference for each week the difference in volume between current week and previous

i have a week of year parameter on my matrix report so user can select multiple weeks to see but each week so the user will have a Week of year parameter from 1 to 52 , they can select as many as they like but the report need to calculate the %difference week on week by volume i.e quantity
[image: Table sample]

Comment: To have any hope of getting help here you'll need to define the input data, and show what you have so far (how are the weekly totals calculated for a start).

Comment: its basically a total across 7 days

Comment: SELECT pos.DivNo
  ,pos.ProductCode
  ,[Description]
  ,[CGNo]
  ,[SCGNo]
  ,p.Retail
  ,w.WeekOfYear
  ,w.FirstDayOfWeek
  ,Sum(Quantity) [Quantity]
  ,sum(pos.Retail) [Retail]
  ,w.NoOfStores
  ,(Sum(Quantity) / w.NoOfStores) USw

Comment: @Richard to put it cimply i need

Comment: @Richard simply* i need sum(quantity)/Previous weeks Sum(quantity)*100

Comment: the report is run by selecting week of year (@WOY) 1 to 52 , so if the user picks @WOY  1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Comment: @Richard what the report should do is sum the quantity for each week, For each week a % difference should also be shown, this will be   the difference in Quantity between the current week and the previous.

Comment: Please add the complete query into the question itself. Code is too hard to read in comments, especially when not formatted as code.